# How to set minimal allowed size for a graphical element?

Tags: gui-construction, options, undocumented, document-creation, size

Starting from version 10.3 there is a documented way to specify a *maximum* allowed size for a graphical element via `UpTo`:

```
Table[Graphics[Circle[], Background -> LightGreen, ImageSize -> UpTo[50], 
  AspectRatio -> n], {n, {0.5, 1, 2}}]
```

> [image: output]

But is it possible to specify a *minimum* allowed size as well?

P.S. The question is intended to collect methods for setting the minimum size for *different* graphic elements.

Comment: Is this what you want? ImageSize-> {{widthmin,widthmax]},{heightmin,heightmax}}

Comment: @DanielHuber The question is intended to collect methods for setting the minimum size for *different* graphic elements. This syntax logically follows from my answer, I just hadn't tested it.

Answer (score 4):

At least for `Pane`, there are undocumented syntax forms of `ImageSize` for this:

```
ImageSize -> {{minWidth, maxWidth}, Automatic}
```

and

```
ImageSize -> {Automatic, {minHeight, maxHeight}}
```

where `minWidth`, `maxWidth`, `minHeight` and `maxHeight` can be a number or `Full`. Instead of `Automatic` can be a number or a symbolic size specification like `Large`, `Small`, etc.

These forms are found by searching through the `InputForm` of the bundled Documentation notebooks.

---

**UPDATE**

Testing shows that this syntax works also for `Graphics`:

```
Table[Graphics[Circle[], Background -> LightGreen, ImageSize -> {{35, 50}, 50}, 
  AspectRatio -> n], {n, {0.5, 1, 2}}]
```

> [image: out]

---

**UPDATE 2**

It also works for `Button`:

```
Grid@Table[{Button["Text", Null, Background -> LightGreen, 
    ImageSize -> {{minWidth, Full}, Automatic}], 
   ImageSize -> {{minWidth, Full}, Automatic}}, {minWidth, 0, 90, 20}]
```

> [image: out]